# CMD how to pass parameters to script and save to file name of one of the parameters

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, dos

I want to pass the following parameters to a script:

```
myscript.cmd "Foo" "Bar" "File"
```

Where the 3rd parameter should be with added extension `.log`

In this example it should be `File.log`

```
SET logFile = "%~3" + .log
echo logFileName is "%logFile%"

echo %date% %time% got parameters "%~1" "%~2" >> "%logFile%"
```

Should be something like the script above, but not being able to make it work

Answer (score 2):

Three problems, quotes (included in the value of the variable), spaces (you have included spaces in the name of the variable) and concatenation (there is no concatenation operator in batch files)

You have defined a variable named `logFile_`, with an aditional space (represented by the underscore) in its name, and the assigned value is the literal `_"File"_+_.log` (as before, underscores represent spaces)

The line

```
SET logFile = "%~3" + .log
           ^ ^^   ^^^^  Unneeded/problematic characters
```

Should be

```
SET "logFile=%~3.log"
```

No aditional spaces and the quotes are not included in the value, they just delimit the assignment to prevent problems with special characters or aditional spaces at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces around the = and remove extraneous quotes.

```
SET logFile=%~3.log
echo logFileName is "%logFile%"

echo %date% %time% got parameters "%~1" "%~2" >> "%logFile%"
```

That works for me.